# OpenCV: Undefined reference to xcb_poll_for_reply

Tags: c++, opencv, compiler-errors, xcb

As of late I have been getting the following error whenever I try to compile any program that uses the open cv libraries, I use g++ to compile:

```
g++ Example.cpp -o Ex `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
```

No matter the content of the file (I have checked with programs that worked a couple of weeks ago) I always get the following error:

```
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_reply64'
/usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_reply64'
```

Do you have any idea of what might be the cause? (and how to fix it)

An example program that fails to compile:

```
#include "path/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "path/opencv/highgui.h"

using namespace cv;

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  Mat image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE) ;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you recently changed the way you are compiling with g++?

Comment: @ross I am using a front end machine at my work so I am not sure if there was any change with the g++ compilation... Is there any way for me to check if there was one?

Answer (score 0):

Add **-lxcb** to your command line (this will instruct the linker linking w/ the xcb library). Please make sure the *64b* version of xcb is in the linker path (you can always put it explicitly via the **-L** switch)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got:  `/path/lib/libxcb-shm.so.0: undefined reference to xcb_get_reply_fds` and `/path/lib/libxcb-shm.so.0: undefined reference to xcb_send_fd`

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by some changes done to the libX11.so.6, talked with the FE machines support and they fixed it.